# iterate a sequence, accessing current item and the following in each step

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

say, I have 5 javaScript Objects stored in a vector:

```
(def v [o1 o2 o3 o4 o5])
```

Each o them has a method "connect", which gets another object as a parameter.

Manually I would now:

```
o1.connect(o2);
o2.connect(o3);
o3.connect(o4);
o4.connect(o5);
```

What would be a good approach to automate this?

only some weird solutions come to my mind: as:

```
(doseq [[a b] (zipmap (butlast v) (rest v))]
  (.connect a b))
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `partition`:

```
(doseq [[a b] (partition 2 1 v)]
  (.connect a b))
```

Comment: fantastic. didn't know that partition accepts a padding parameter.